# Grabbing just the URL of an href using HTMLAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

Here is the HTML source I'm trying to parse:

```
<a style='white-space: nowrap;' href='/AuthorStories-4931/dreamfall.htm'><img class='donoricon' alt='(Current Donor)'  title='(Current Donor)' src='http://static.tthf.me/images/donors/Current%20Donor.gif'/>dreamfall</a>
```

Here is the code I'm using:

```
authorLink = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//a[contains(@href, 'AuthorStories')]").OuterHtml;
```

This grabs the link correctly, but it also captures the img as well. The only part I want to grab is the href segment. Any suggestions on how to parse out just that particular section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*[Haven't touched HtmlAgilityPack in a few years, but this should be generally true]*

Instead of taking `OuterHtml`, there should be an `Attributes` array on the node returned by `SelectSingleNode`, you should be able to get `href` from there.

Comment: That put me on the right track, thank you. This works perfectly:

    authorLink = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//a[contains(@href, 'AuthorStories')]").Attributes["href"].Value;
    authorLink = authorLink.Insert(0, "<a href='http://www.tthfanfic.org");
    authorLink = authorLink + "'>" + authorName + "</a>";

Unfortunately it's a bit unwieldy for such a simple task. Is this how you'd recommend doing these steps, or would you do this in some other manner?

Comment: Are you trying to edit the document nodes, or you just want to form some html for another document?

Comment: If you plan to create a new string, I'd go with something like:
    var href = "tthfanfic.org" + doc.....Attributes["href"].Value;
    var newLink = string.Format("<a href='{0}'>{1}</a>", href, authorName);

[haven't touched C# in a few months, so that could be iffy :P]